# URL Decoding - What on earth is this?

Tags: base64, urlencode, urldecode

I sincerely apologize if I'm in the wrong place with this question.

I'm hoping someone out there might know what kind of encoding is used here? It's google flights..

https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhpCagcIARID WVVMagcIARIDWUhNEgoyMDIxLTA4LTExcgcIARIDRE9IcgcIARIDVEJTcgcIARIDQVVIcgcIARIDRFhCGkJqBwgBEgNET0hqBwgBEgNUQlNqBwgBEgNBVUhqBwgBEgNEWEISCjIwMjEtMDgtMTVyBwgBEgNZVUxyBwgBEgNZSE1wAYIBCwj___________8BQAFIA5gBAQ

I've been running parts of it through a Base64 decoder all day but I just can't see (perhaps I just don't understand) how this is Base64 entirely.

Parts seem like it's just Base64 but then others not, same with Base64 URL encoding.

Does anyone have any clue what kind of beast this is or can anyone offer any pointers as to what else it could be?

Comment: Running the string through a base64 decoder provides this: BjYULjYHM
2021-08-11rDOHrTBSrAUHrDXBBjDOHjTBSjAUHjDXB
2021-08-15rYULrYHMp@H

Comment: Looks like it gives you some Airport codes and the dates EX. YUL is Montreal